# How to integrate fraction

Tags: integration

Hi can anybody give me some hint how to integrate this type of fractions

$$\int \frac{1}{(x^2 +a)^2} dx $$ where $ a \in \mathbb N $

Thanks

Comment: If $a>0$, you could use an appropriate "reverse trig substitution" (e.g., $x=\sqrt a \tan t$). If $a<0$, use Partial Fractions.

Comment: Oops, I didn't see the "$\Bbb N$". Looks like a reverse trig substitution.

Comment: Using David Mitra suggestion (x = y Sqrt[a]) leads to a very simple integral.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take the integral

$$\int \frac{dx}{x^2+a^2}$$
and we do an integration by parts:

$$\int 1\cdot\frac{dx}{x^2+a^2}=\frac{x}{x^2+a^2}+2\int\frac{x^2dx}{(x^2+a^2)^2}$$
for the last integral we add and subtract $1$ in the numerator and we find
$$\int\frac{dx}{(x^2+a^2)^2}=\frac 1 2\left(\int \frac{dx}{x^2+a^2}+\frac{x}{x^2+a^2}\right)$$
Notice that $$\int \frac{dx}{x^2+a^2}=\frac 1 a \arctan \left(\frac x a\right)+C$$

Answer (score 0):

take x=√a tanø

then $$\int \frac{1}{(x^2 + a)^2} \, dx = \int \frac{1}{\sqrt{a³} \sec^2(\phi)} \, d\phi = \int \frac{\cos^2(\phi)}{\sqrt{a³}} \, d\phi.$$
now solve it

Comment: Where does the cubic root come from? Could you try using MathJax for formatting the math formulas?

Comment: sorry its my mistake but now i correct it

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$$
\int{1 \over x^{2} +a}\,\dd x
= {1 \over \root{a}}\int{1 \over \pars{x/\root{a}}^{2} +1}\,{\dd x \over \root{a}}
=a^{-1/2}\arctan\pars{a^{-1/2}x}
$$

> Derive both members respect of $a$:
> $$
> -\int{1 \over \pars{x^{2} +a}^2}\,\dd x=
> -\,\half\,a^{-3/2}\arctan\pars{a^{-1/2}x} +
> a^{-1/2}\,{-a^{-3/2}x/2 \over \pars{a^{-1/2}x}^{2} + 1}
> $$

$$\color{#00f}{\large%
\int{1 \over \pars{x^{2} +a}^2}\,\dd x=
{1 \over 2a\root{a}}\,\arctan\pars{x \over \root{a}} +
{x \over 2a\pars{x^{2} + a}}} + \mbox{a constant}
$$